# Port forwarding ubuntu server - iptables

Tags: networking, linux-networking, port-forwarding, wireguard

I would like assistance in connecting to a WireGuard server that is currently being censored by my ISP. To overcome this restriction, I am attempting to set up port forwarding from my VPS to the WireGuard server to achieve this : My laptop --> My VPS --> wireguard-on-another-server.

Let's consider this :

My vps ip : 1.2.3.4.

The wireguard server I want to connect to : 5.6.7.8:51820

---

Here is what I did so far on my vps :

1 - I enabled net.ipv4.ip_forward

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

2 - using iptables I redirected incoming UDP traffic from port 51820 to the wireguard server at port 51820

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 51820 -j DNAT --to 5.6.7.8:51820
```

3 -

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp -d 5.6.7.8 --dport 51820 -j MASQUERADE
```

But it doesn't work, I have no clue what I should do. I'm convinced I just need to fix something with my iptables. Any suggestions please ?

---

Yes, port 51820 udp is open on my VPS.

The wireguard server works when connecting to it directly using another ISP.

Thank you

Comment: Those rules work fine for me. I would probably want to verify that both legs of this connection work independently, running `ncat -u 1.2.3.4 51820` on your laptop paired with `ncat -ukl 51820` on the vps would do nicely, and to verify the VPS can connect to the wireguard server I would probably just set up a wireguard interface on the VPS and check it's working.

Comment: Incidentally, if you have a VPS, is there a reason you don't want to run your wireguard server there instead?

Comment: The two legs of the connection works.
My goal is to connect to that wireguard server specifically. It can't be a routing issue ?

Comment: Can you ping anything through the tunnel at all?

Comment: You might also consider just using 2 wireguard tunnels for the 2 hops you want to do, and enable ip forwarding on the VPS

Comment: There are more things to try to diagnose this issue, but writing a tutorial for that is a bit outside the scope of this. I built a model of your setup, and everything works totally fine using those rules verbatim (save for IPs). I ran `tcpdump` on my analogue for your VPS to show [what that traffic should look like](https://pastebin.com/w4Mxfjr2) (this is one ping through the wg interface). It might also be helpful to share your wireguard configuration

Comment: Thanks for your help.

I cannot ping anything through the tunnel.

So I did some more testing to hopefully figure out what's wrong but it's a bit over my head.

1 - I installed a wireguard server on my VPS on 50301 port.
2 - I used the same commands on my initial post to do port forwarding from 51820 to 50301 on the same machine
3 - I kept port 50301 closed and 51820 open

I connected successfully to my wireguard server through 51820 port.

So maybe it is a routing issue ?

Comment: Port forwarding works when it is set up on the same machine, but it doesn't function when attempting to forward ports to another WireGuard server on a different machine.

Comment: If you get a chance to have a look at the output of `tcpdump` that might be helpful